# Fancybox navigation right bottom corner

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

Is it possible to make navigation in fancybox to be located on the right bottom corner and having respond to screen/fancybox image scaling while I making screen bigger/smaller?

fancybox template example http://fiddle.jshell.net/t91p3g7s/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=t91p3g7s

my goal:

navigation in right bottom corner of fancybox window:

[image: navigation in right bottom corner of fancybox window]

Comment: AFAIK, right bottom corner is known to anyone who has programming skills, so there is no need to share a large image. Instead it would be nice to share your code here and try to be exact while asking questions. Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section

Comment: @Trix, you right, will try to make clear question next time. Thank you for feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fancybox 2 exists two properties to move your popup, leftRatio and topRatio by default both receive the value 0.5 what means center, in leftRatio if you put 1.0 your popup will go to the right if you put 0 to the left, topRatio if you put 1.0 will go to bottom and 0 to the top.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  try{
   $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        helpers: {
            buttons: {
                tpl: '<div id="fancybox-buttons"><ul>' +
                    '<li><a class="btnToggle" title="Toggle size" href="javascript:;"></a></li>' +
                    '<li><a class="btnClose" title="Close" href="javascript:;"></a></li>' +
                    '</ul></div>'
            }
        },
        leftRatio: 1.0,
        topRatio: 0
    });
   } catch(e){
   console.log(e.message);
   }
});
```

```css
#fancybox-buttons ul {
    /* 166 for 4 buttons */
    width: 86px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>

<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

Comment: I don't see how this puts the navigation in the bottom right corner.

Comment: It's only works in fancybox 2 @showdev you can see by put my code snippet in full page screen.

Comment: You've used `leftRatio` and `topRatio`. That adjust the position of the lightbox, not navigation.

Comment: Showdev, it was my bad that i formulated not strictly the question. Actually code that Hiago gave make the whole positioning with navigation, so his answer is correct. I tried to make the question more clearly and created this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110386/fancybox-left-and-right-arrow-button-on-the-right-bottom-of-sliding-picture , so it focuses this question more deeply.