# Fancybox left and right arrow button on the right-bottom of sliding picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

Just trying to figure out how to change options of fancybox buttons to snap them on the right bottom corner of sliding images.

fancybox template example http://fiddle.jshell.net/t91p3g7s/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=t91p3g7s

arrows position that i want to achieve:
[buttons right-bottom corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OXcU.jpg)

Comment: Why the question is downgraded? It is different from previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force on CSS. It's simple.

Just add this css:

```
.fancybox-next {
    bottom: 10px;
    top: auto;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
.fancybox-prev {
    bottom: 10px;
    top: auto;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    right: 60px;
    left: auto;
}
.fancybox-next span, .fancybox-prev span{
    visibility: visible !important;
    display: block !important;
}
```

Or Just click here.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/t91p3g7s/6/

:)